# Web3 empty response when geth not synced

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, synchronization

I am running my own geth node and doing some test transactions.

When making a transaction trough web3 I get an response of transaction information. But sometimes it happens that my node is not fully in sync so when I make a transaction from geth I get an empty response.

Since I want to save all the transaction hashes in my databas this is a problem.

How should I handle this kind of situation? Is there a way to get transaction hash from web3 anyway if this happens? I know geth shows it but it is not returned by web3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using web3 1.0 and trying to send a transaction to a contract. For example to make a tokens transfer and obtain the transaction hash you can do this:

```
token.methods.transfer(recipient, amount)
.send({ from: owner })
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    console.log(hash);
});
```